# Momentum shell renormalization coupling constant expansion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, renormalization

Whilst studying momentum shell renormalization in Altland & Simons Condensed Matter Field Theory (Chapter 8.2 page 423) I came across a technique  which puzzled me a bit.

It starts off with the normal procedure of dividing the action/fields ($\theta$) (specific action does not matter for my question) into slow and fast ones, $\theta = \theta_s + \theta_f$, integrating slow ones up to $|\omega_n| < \Lambda/b$ and fast ones between $ \Lambda / b <|\omega_n| < \Lambda$. After doing this you can split the action in a part that only depends on $\theta_s$, one that only depends on $\theta_f$ and one that has combinations of both. Next they define $e^{-S_{eff} \ [\theta_s]} \equiv e^{-S_{s} \ [\theta_s]} \langle e^{-S_U [\theta_s\ ,\ \theta_f\ ]} \rangle_f $, where $\langle . . . \rangle_f \equiv \int D \theta_f e^{-S_f [\theta_f \ ]} (...)$, with $S_{eff}$ the effective action, $S_s$ the slow field action, $S_f$ the fast field action and $S_U$ the combined term. Here comes the sketchy part for me: They assume the coupling constant is small, expanding the exponent in the brackets: $ e^{-S_{s} \ [\theta_s]} \langle e^{-S_U [\theta_s\ ,\ \theta_f\ ]} \rangle_f = e^{-S_{s} \ [\theta_s]} \langle 1 - S_U + ... \rangle_f$ and then **re-exponentiate** this to $ \approx e^{-S_{s} \ [\theta_s]} e^{-\langle S_U \ [\theta_s \ ,\theta_f \ ]  \rangle_f}$.

My questions are the following:

1. How is this done mathematically? The re-exponentiating does not exactly add up when I try to reproduce it.
2. Why is it justified to do this expansion and exponentiating in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is standard power-series expansion, if I understand correctly. We start by $e^{-S_U} = 1-S_U+O(S_U^2)$ which you can say is the definition of exponential. Then we take the expectation value as
$$ \int\! D\theta_f e^{-S_f[\theta_f]}\left\{1-S_U[\theta_f, \theta_s]+O(S_U^2)\right\}$$ is still well defined (the $S_U^2$ term just gives you higher-order interaction terms), and this, in turn, just give us numbers. The expectation value of $1$ is also $1$, by requirement $\int\! D\theta_f e^{-S_f[\theta_f]} = 1$ (otherwise we divide by this quantity). So we get $\langle e^{-S_U} \rangle_f = 1-\langle S_U \rangle_f + \langle O(S_U^2) \rangle_f$ which has the same linear series expansion as $e^{-\langle S_U \rangle_f}$, so we can replace one with the other, keeping in mind that the approximation is valid only up to linear term in the interactions described in $S_U$, and everything is perturbative with the caveats it entails.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, but why is the approximation only valid in linear terms? Is there a specific reason besides tossing sub-leading terms?

Comment: we only keep the leading term in the expansion mainly because it is the easiest and simplest approach. If it works - great. If not, we must try different approaches (either go to higher-terms or try some non-perturbative techniques). Basically we physicist are a lazy bunch and if we can get away with an easy calculation that works we don't see a reason to carry out a more complex one